# Insert html content to mysql table

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I need to insert html content to mysql table.but script cut part of html content.
Html content is as below.

```
        <div data-plugin-lightbox data-plugin-options='{"delegate": "a", "type": "image", "gallery": {"enabled": true}}'>
```

i cannot upload all content.mysql table has 
Only

```
 <div data-plugin-lightbox data-plugin-options={"
```

How can i insert any html content to mysql table.

Comment: what is the data type of mysql field in which you are saving the html?

Comment: No i cannot even echo the content from external php file.( <?php echo $_POST['data']) I used jquery ajax form submit.

Answer (score 2):

Seems a double quote related issue  .. you should escape the double quote for json

```
<div data-plugin-lightbox data-plugin-options='{\"delegate\": \"a\", \"type\":    .......
```

or the issue could be related to your string assignment in php

the assignment

```
$sql = "< <div data-plugin-lightbox data-plugin-options='{"delegate": "
```

break on the second double quotes

Answer (score 2):

HTML tegs can be inserted into mysql in plain text.But you should echo that content which you inserted properly

Answer (score 2):

use htmlspecialchars($str) before you store in DB.

and use htmlspecialchars_decode($str) after reading from DB.

Answer (score 2):

Try using htmlspecialchars() on the string to put into the DB, and then, when pulling it back out, use htmlspecialchars_decode(). Might make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

You should always escape your strings before using them in SQL queries, to avoid the kind of problems you have here and for [security reasons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

PHP's mysqli extenstion comes with the [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) that is here just for this purpose and respects the connection's charset:

Object oriented style:

```
$var = $mysqli->real_escape_string($var);
```

Procedural style:

```
$var = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_link, $var);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.
Reason is ' & q u o t ; '.
 Used this to avoid 
     var NewString = text.replace(/&/g, "xxx");

thank you all

Answer (score 0):

```
htmlentities($message, ENT_QUOTES);
```

It works for me for both double and single quotes in HTML.